# Rails3: What REST URLs for the different pages of a multi-pages wizard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes, formwizard

I am new to Rails and its all-REST concept.

I am writing an exam website with Rails3.
During an examination, a user has to answer questions that are spread over 4 pages (kind of like a wizard).

**How does this translate in REST?**
I will probably have an `Examination` model with an `/examinations/new` URL, but I need 4 URLs for each of the 4 pages, how to achieve this in Rails3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds are this http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms will answer your question.

Comment: +1 It is for Rails2 but I will try, it looks exactly like what I need, thanks! :-)